Как написать драйвер/sdk на Android чтобы была «бесшовная» печать на Canon LBP 6030B?
Под "бесшовной" печатью я подразумеваю вывод pdf-файла на печать без взаимодействия с интерфейсом (служба). Printing framework на сколько я знаю работает только из активити и там присутствует интерфейс. Можно ли послать pdf-файл на принтер используя usb api или надо писать низкоуровневый драйвер для конкретного принтера. И если надо писать драйвер, где бы я мог найти документацию по его написанию?

Canon Print Service видит ваш принтер?

Забудь про lbp6030 - это хоть и не 6020 который понимает только язык capt который реализован только для i386. Но тут язык принтера ufrii который хоть и имеет поддержку в операционных системах, но все же не имеет открытого кода для перекомпиляции под андроид.
Для вашей задумки лучше взять driverless принтер. Например hp m111w и пулять голый пдф через вайфай на ipp или аналогичную версию без вайфая где можно засунуть пдф в усб.
Если работаем с подножным оборудованием, то смотрите (может попадется) с поддержкой языка pcl или postscript. Этот формат можно сделать опенсорсным конвертором.
